# How to change powershell terminal color(s) or completely turn off the color coding

Tags: powershell, colors, uiaccessibility

My eyes have a hard-time seeing the rainbow of colors that powershell uses.  I need to somehow get a powershell terminal window to display everything (aka, error messages, syntax, output, etc.) with black text on a white background.  AND I need to have this happen in an Azure Cloud Shell and "stick" (meaning if I exit the cloud-shell and come back into it, the terminal window is automagically setup correctly).

Is this doable?  Can someone point me to a script or the correct commands to do this?  OR maybe point me to some accessibility setting?

IT WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Bill

Answer (score 0):

First you need a profile to edit:

```
if ($false -eq (Test-Path $profile)){New-Item $profile -type file}
```

next you can open it in notepad

```
& notepad $profile
```

or vscode

```
& code $profile
```

and save the following as your profile:

```
$console = $host.ui.rawui
$console.backgroundcolor = "black"
$console.foregroundcolor = "white"
$colors = $host.privatedata
$colors.verbosebackgroundcolor = "Black"
$colors.verboseforegroundcolor = "Green"
$colors.warningbackgroundcolor = "Red"
$colors.warningforegroundcolor = "white"
$colors.ErrorBackgroundColor = "Yellow"
$colors.ErrorForegroundColor = "Red"
set-location C:\
clear-host
```

Comment: That's getting close to what I'm looking for.  However, now when I type a command at the prompt, it takes a moment for the command to appear.  And when it does appear the letters are white in a black box.  Better, but somewhat distracting.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem as you Bill. The surrounding colours are changed, but when I type a command, it is with the default colours (white on blue background). I have never found a way to permanently (and programmatically, of course) change the console colours in PowerShell).

Comment: or ">notepad++.exe $Profile "

Answer (score 0):

OP asked for Black & White, not other colors for errors.

Here you are :

```
## NO colored syntax thank you.

$console = $host.ui.rawui
$console.backgroundcolor = "black"
$console.foregroundcolor = "white"
$colors = $host.privatedata
$colors.verbosebackgroundcolor = "Black"
$colors.verboseforegroundcolor = "White"
$colors.warningbackgroundcolor = "Black"
$colors.warningforegroundcolor = "White"
$colors.Errorbackgroundcolor = "Black"
$colors.Errorforegroundcolor = "White"
set-location C:\
clear-host
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the application program theme of appearance into Bright mode. Then I can see black color text and white color background.